# Finding the date of acquisition of Google maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, date

How do i find the date of acquisition of the Google map on QGIS? Please help.

Comment: Can you please *edit* your question and provide more details? Do you happen to mean the satellite images which can be imported with the Openlayers plugin?

Comment: yes exactly that. i got my answer :) Thank u anyway

Comment: Can you share your answer?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using the openlayers plugin (WMS). 
You cannot retrieve it. 
Your best bet is to open google earth, zoom to your study area and look at the bottom of your screen
[see here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-date-of-satellite-images/2964/)

Comment: Yes Google Earth has the date of the imagery.

Comment: Thank u for answering my question @juls :)

Comment: is there really no way to do this programatically? i don't want to believe that the data is available but the only way to get it is zooming around in google earth